# Use SQL to return all unused information for each day in date range

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm terrible at SQL. I have a table within Access with trainer schedules. Each record within the table, **Schedule**, contains the following relevant fields: 
**course_code**, 
**training_date**, 
**start_time**, 
**end_time**, 
**trainer**, 
**room**

I also have a table, **Room**, containing **room_id**, **room_name**, and **room-capacity**. My ultimate goal is to return a query that identifies each room for each date that is not in the schedule.

For example, if *Room F* is scheduled for use on *12/18*, *12/20*, and *12/21*, then I would like to see my final table to show:

```
12/19 | Room F | 8 capacity
12/22 | Room F | 8 capacity
```

when I run the query for date range, 12/18-12/22.

I'm close, but as I said, my SQL is not so hot:

```
SELECT Room.room_name, Room.room_capacity, Schedule.training_date
FROM Room LEFT JOIN Schedule ON Room.[room_id] = Schedule.[room] 
and (Schedule.training_date) Between [Enter Start Date] And [Enter Ending Date]
WHERE ((Schedule.room) Is Null);
```

In this case, it yields

```
| Room F | 8 capacity
```

I just need to include each individual date.

Comment: Do you have a calendar table in this database?

Comment: You are trying to find open schedules for the rooms, correct? Change your `LEFT JOIN` to a `RIGHT JOIN`, or better yet, switch your primary table to be `schedule`.

Comment: I do not have a calendar table. If you feel that would help, I could create one. I assume it would be just a single field with one record per date? I suppose I could also include a field for holidays.

I am indeed trying to find open schedules for the rooms, Shawn.

Comment: Sorry, my suggestion will only work if a calendar table is also joined. Every database should have a calendar table. They are one of the handiest things in databases. :-)  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Comment: Is your database Access or another flavor of SQL? It will take a little more work for Access, but is still doable.

Comment: It is Access. I'll add that to my original question. I'll also look up the calendar table.

Comment: My link above from Aaron Bertrand will give you some good background in what a calendar table does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each day is in the schedule at least once, you can use that as the "calendar" table:

```
select r.*, s.dte
from (select distinct training_date as dte from schedule) as s,
     room as r
where not exists (select 1
                  from schedule as s2
                  where s2.training_date = s.dte and s2.room = r.room_id
                 );
```

Comment: If each day was in the `Schedule` table, then the original query with `WHERE Schedule.room IS NULL` would work.

Comment: @Shawn . . . No, it would not.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, I meant if the calendar table was joined to it.

Comment: This is great. Thank you. Where is the best place to insert my prompt for the start date and end date? I do have a calendar table linked to my schedule table with Schedule's training_date is linked to Calendar's calendar_date. I've also added a day_of_week index code. I'm trying to find a way to exclude weekends (1 and 7), but that's not in the original question.

Comment: The best way to exclude weekends is to identify them in your calendar table and then filter them out.

Comment: I would also filter your joined calendar table by the start/end dates

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to use a Date Dimension / Calendar table to get what you want out of T-SQL. Acces implementation of SQL is *much* more primitive, but the below should still be able to be modified to work.

*Note: This also uses the calendar table to factor for weekends and holidays.*

**Current Schedules:**

- Room F = 12/18,12/20,12/21
- Room G = 12/05,12/10
- Room H = 12/18,12/20
- Room X = No schedule

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3e17d/2)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE schedule ( id int, training_date date, room int ) ;
INSERT INTO schedule ( id, training_date, room )
VALUES
      (1, '20171218', 1)
    , (2, '20171220', 1)
    , (3, '20171221', 1)
    , (4, '20171205', 3)
    , (5, '20171210', 3)
    , (6, '20171218', 4)
    , (7, '20171220', 4)
;

CREATE TABLE room ( room_id int, room_name varchar(20), room_capacity int ) ;
INSERT INTO room ( room_id, room_name, room_capacity )
VALUES 
      ( 1, 'Room F', 8 )
    , ( 2, 'Room X', 42 )
    , ( 3, 'Room G', 10 )
    , ( 4, 'Room H', 15 )
;

/* ******** MAKE SIMPLE CALENDAR TABLE ******** */

CREATE TABLE dateDim (
      theDate             DATE        NOT NULL
    , IsWeekend           BIT         DEFAULT 0
    , IsHoliday           BIT         DEFAULT 0
    , IsWorkDay           BIT         DEFAULT 0
);

/* Populate basic details of dates. */
INSERT dateDim(theDate, IsWeekend, IsHoliday) 
SELECT d
  , CONVERT(BIT, CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,d) IN (1,7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  , CONVERT(BIT, CASE WHEN d = '20171225' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) /* Christmas. Calc others. */
FROM (
    SELECT d = DATEADD(DAY, rn - 1, '20171201')
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, '20171201', '20171231')) 
            rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
        FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
        ORDER BY s1.[object_id]
    ) AS x
) AS y ;

/* If not a weekend or holiday, it's a WorkDay. */
UPDATE dateDim 
SET IsWorkDay = CASE WHEN IsWeekend = 0 AND IsHoliday = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
;
```

**MS T-SQL Query**:

```
SELECT Room.room_name, Room.room_capacity, dateDim.theDate
FROM Room 
CROSS APPLY dateDim  /* CROSS APPLY doesn't work in Access */
LEFT JOIN Schedule ON Room.room_id = Schedule.room
  AND dateDim.theDate = Schedule.training_date
WHERE Schedule.room Is Null
  AND dateDim.isWeekend = 0
  AND dateDim.isHoliday = 0
ORDER BY dateDim.theDate, room.room_name
```

**Access Query**: I believe this one will work in Access.

```
SELECT Room.room_name, Room.room_capacity, c1.theDate
FROM Room 
INNER JOIN ( 
  SELECT theDate 
  FROM dateDim 
  WHERE isWeekend = 0 
    AND isHoliday = 0 
    AND theDate BETWEEN '12/15/2017' AND '12/22/2017' -- To filter by your start/end dates
) c1 ON 1=1
LEFT JOIN Schedule ON Room.room_id = Schedule.room
  AND c1.theDate = Schedule.training_date
WHERE Schedule.room Is Null
ORDER BY c1.theDate, room.room_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3e17d/2/0)**:

```
| room_name | room_capacity |    theDate |
|-----------|---------------|------------|
|    Room F |             8 | 2017-12-01 |
|    Room G |            10 | 2017-12-01 |
|    Room H |            15 | 2017-12-01 |
|    Room X |            42 | 2017-12-01 |
|    Room F |             8 | 2017-12-04 |
|    Room G |            10 | 2017-12-04 |
|    Room H |            15 | 2017-12-04 |
|    Room X |            42 | 2017-12-04 |
|    Room F |             8 | 2017-12-05 |
|    Room H |            15 | 2017-12-05 |
|    Room X |            42 | 2017-12-05 |
|    Room F |             8 | 2017-12-06 |
|    Room G |            10 | 2017-12-06 |
|    Room H |            15 | 2017-12-06 |
|    Room X |            42 | 2017-12-06 |
|    Room F |             8 | 2017-12-07 |
|    Room G |            10 | 2017-12-07 |
|    Room H |            15 | 2017-12-07 |
|    Room X |            42 | 2017-12-07 |
|    Room F |             8 | 2017-12-08 |
|    Room G |            10 | 2017-12-08 |
|    Room H |            15 | 2017-12-08 |
|    Room X |            42 | 2017-12-08 |
|    Room F |             8 | 2017-12-11 |
|    Room G |            10 | 2017-12-11 |
|    Room H |            15 | 2017-12-11 |
|    Room X |            42 | 2017-12-11 |
|    Room F |             8 | 2017-12-12 |
|    Room G |            10 | 2017-12-12 |
|    Room H |            15 | 2017-12-12 |
|    Room X |            42 | 2017-12-12 |
|    Room F |             8 | 2017-12-13 |
|    Room G |            10 | 2017-12-13 |
|    Room H |            15 | 2017-12-13 |
|    Room X |            42 | 2017-12-13 |
|    Room F |             8 | 2017-12-14 |
|    Room G |            10 | 2017-12-14 |
|    Room H |            15 | 2017-12-14 |
|    Room X |            42 | 2017-12-14 |
|    Room F |             8 | 2017-12-15 |
|    Room G |            10 | 2017-12-15 |
|    Room H |            15 | 2017-12-15 |
|    Room X |            42 | 2017-12-15 |
|    Room G |            10 | 2017-12-18 |
|    Room X |            42 | 2017-12-18 |
|    Room F |             8 | 2017-12-19 |
|    Room G |            10 | 2017-12-19 |
|    Room H |            15 | 2017-12-19 |
|    Room X |            42 | 2017-12-19 |
|    Room G |            10 | 2017-12-20 |
|    Room X |            42 | 2017-12-20 |
|    Room G |            10 | 2017-12-21 |
|    Room H |            15 | 2017-12-21 |
|    Room X |            42 | 2017-12-21 |
|    Room F |             8 | 2017-12-22 |
|    Room G |            10 | 2017-12-22 |
|    Room H |            15 | 2017-12-22 |
|    Room X |            42 | 2017-12-22 |
|    Room F |             8 | 2017-12-26 |
|    Room G |            10 | 2017-12-26 |
|    Room H |            15 | 2017-12-26 |
|    Room X |            42 | 2017-12-26 |
|    Room F |             8 | 2017-12-27 |
|    Room G |            10 | 2017-12-27 |
|    Room H |            15 | 2017-12-27 |
|    Room X |            42 | 2017-12-27 |
|    Room F |             8 | 2017-12-28 |
|    Room G |            10 | 2017-12-28 |
|    Room H |            15 | 2017-12-28 |
|    Room X |            42 | 2017-12-28 |
|    Room F |             8 | 2017-12-29 |
|    Room G |            10 | 2017-12-29 |
|    Room H |            15 | 2017-12-29 |
|    Room X |            42 | 2017-12-29 |
```

**[Access-method Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3e17d/4/0)**:

```
| room_name | room_capacity |    theDate |
|-----------|---------------|------------|
|    Room F |             8 | 2017-12-15 |
|    Room G |            10 | 2017-12-15 |
|    Room H |            15 | 2017-12-15 |
|    Room X |            42 | 2017-12-15 |
|    Room G |            10 | 2017-12-18 |
|    Room X |            42 | 2017-12-18 |
|    Room F |             8 | 2017-12-19 |
|    Room G |            10 | 2017-12-19 |
|    Room H |            15 | 2017-12-19 |
|    Room X |            42 | 2017-12-19 |
|    Room G |            10 | 2017-12-20 |
|    Room X |            42 | 2017-12-20 |
|    Room G |            10 | 2017-12-21 |
|    Room H |            15 | 2017-12-21 |
|    Room X |            42 | 2017-12-21 |
|    Room F |             8 | 2017-12-22 |
|    Room G |            10 | 2017-12-22 |
|    Room H |            15 | 2017-12-22 |
|    Room X |            42 | 2017-12-22 |
```

Comment: Also note that your calendar table should essentially cover any date that can or will ever possibly apply to any table or query from your database. ie I usually create a calendar table that spans 1/1/1950 to 12/31/2049 or 100 years. If I need a bigger range, it's fairly easy to adjust.